# Laravel foreach table years month count

Tags: laravel, foreach, laravel-10

I created this in the controller, and if I go to check it works correctly, I made this in the blade view file, and I see everything correctly. Still, now I want to see only specific years and not all together, but I don't know how to make it work like I want. Right now, I see all the years that are present in the database with their respective counts, but I would like to see only specific years and not all in one list as I see it now. I want to create a column with a particular year and display only what interests me. Can anyone help me?

```
$test = DB::table('tickets')
      ->selectRaw('YEAR(created_at) as anno, MONTH(created_at) as mese, count(id) as totale')
      ->groupBy('anno', 'mese')
      ->get();

<table>
 <tbody>
   @foreach($test as $tes)
     @php
      \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('it');
     @endphp
     <tr>
       <td>{{($tes->anno)}}</td>
       <td>{{\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m',$tes->mese)->translatedFormat('F')}}</td>
       <td>{{$tes->totale}}</td>
    </tr>
   @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your query to include a `WHERE` clause that filters the data based on only the years you want.

```
$yearsOfInterest = [2022, 2023];

$test = DB::table('tickets')
    ->selectRaw('YEAR(created_at) as anno, MONTH(created_at) as mese, count(id) as totale')
    ->whereIn(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at)'), $yearsOfInterest)
    ->groupBy('anno', 'mese')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, I was fixed in the blade file view configuration and I didn't think of anything like that, now I have the list as I wished to have, thanks a lot for the help